# Steam game purchase statistics?

Tags: steam

Is it possible to view how many times any given game on Steam was purchased or downloaded? [Steam & Game Stats](http://store.steampowered.com/stats/) only seems to list the top 100 games (but doesn't include purchases) - is there a way to get this same information for any given title on Steam?

Comment: At a guess I'd say no, but there might be some enterprising nerd out there who's found a way to get at this information.

Comment: There's probably an API you can hit, although that's heading into Game Dev territory, which is out of Arqade's expertise. If that's what you're looking for however, I'd say check out [Gamedev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), one of our sister sites.

Comment: I doubt sales statistics are made available to the public, even through an API.

Comment: My new answer has exactly the info requested. :)

Answer (score 13):

Valve doesn't release the sales information of games on Steam. They do share their statistics with the developers of the games, but the developer decides whether to share this information further.
[Source](http://www.mcvuk.com/news/read/digital-charts-wont-pick-up-steam)

It may be possible to deduce some statistics from the publicly available information, but I have yet to see a public API that gives access to more in-depth information than that available on the [Steam & Game Stats](http://store.steampowered.com/stats/) page.

Comment: "but the developer decides whether to share this information" Actually this is not true. In many cases, Valve does not permit developers/publishers to share this information, as in the case of Interstellar Marines.

Comment: Can you supply a reference for it, and I will edit it into the answer?

Answer (score 13):

**Steam Spy** is a website allows you to [search for a specific game](http://steamspy.com/search.php), to get estimated sales numbers and hours played.

Although Valve [doesn't make such data public](http://www.mcvuk.com/news/read/digital-charts-wont-pick-up-steam), it is possible to estimate it, based on what data *is* public. Steam Spy does exactly this by random sampling of public user profiles, which list what games that user owns and how many hours they've played. They then multiply by the total number of Steam users. You can read in full about the methods they use, [over here](http://steamspy.com/about).