# Anyway to know number of all players for Steam games?

Tags: steam, achievements

In Steam achievements it always gives:

> % of all
>   players

Is there anyway to know total number of players though?

Comment: Are you interested in the total number of downloads? If so, [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142620/steam-game-purchase-statistics) might answer your question.

Comment: Well I guess my question also entails: what are they basing the % off?

Comment: That's an interesting but separate question. My hunch is that it's based off of downloads, since games that give you achievements for opening the game still have less than 100% completion. Open a new question and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no native way to do it*, but you can do certain math calculations with the information shown on [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/).

With [Counter-Strike: Global Offensive](https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/) and [Shot With Their Pants Down](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/CSGO/achievements) as our example, we follow this steps:

#### Search the game on SteamDB

[image: Search bar on SteamDB]
[image: Counter-Strike: Global Offensive on the list]

#### Select "Graphs & Spy" on the left side

[image: Select the menu]

#### We grab the number of owners (in this case, 39.980.725)

[image: SteamSpy to the rescue]

#### A calculation is done with the achievement percentage

[image: Percentage that completed "Shot With Their Pants Down"]

> 0.786 * 39980725 = 31424849.85

An approximated of 31.424.850 players got the achievement.

**Asterisk Note*:** You can find extensions and user scripts for Firefox and Chrome, but that will require work setting everything up.

Answer (score 8):

If you install the [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) addon for Chrome/Firefox, it will show you player-statistics from [steamspy.com](http://steamspy.com/app/730) on the game's Steam Store page

[image: CS:GO statistics]